# React.js variables not rendering in css with tailwind css

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
import React from "react";
import carousel from "../assets/index";
import Image from "next/image";

const threeD = () => {
    const length = carousel.length;
    const cardWidth = 288;
    const cardsGap = 4;
    const circumference = length * cardWidth + (length - 1 * 4);
    return (
        <div className={`carouselBox`}>
            <div
                className={`flex gap-[${cardsGap}px] w-[${circumference}px] h-[${circumference}px]`}
            >
                {carousel.map((item, index) => (
                    <Image
                        key={index}
                        src={item}
                        alt="yhello"
                        className={`w-[${cardWidth}px] card`}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default threeD;
```

it is my code i want width and height from variables but it is not rendering Please suggest me any solution .

```
const [cardWidth, setCardWidth] = useState(288)
```

I have used useState hook but it is not geting the width from variables is any solution for it

Comment: I think your class name is wrong. Shouldn't this be w-10?

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind does not generate classes at runtime. Which means `w-[${someVariable}px]` would not work. Why not just use the `width` prop on `<Image />`?

```js
import React from "react";
import carousel from "../assets/index";
import Image from "next/image";

const threeD = () => {
    const length = carousel.length;
    const cardWidth = 288;
    const cardsGap = 4;
    const circumference = length * cardWidth + (length - 1 * 4);
    return (
        <div className={`carouselBox`}>
            <div
                className={`flex gap-[${cardsGap}px] w-[${circumference}px] h-[${circumference}px]`}
            >
                {carousel.map((item, index) => (
                    <Image
                        key={index}
                        src={item}
                        alt="yhello"
                        className="card"
                        width={cardWidth}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default threeD;
```